# My bootstrap has conflicts with my css in React JS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, jsx

When I put the bootstrap link in `<head></head>` my style change without any reason.

Without bootstrap link:
[image]

With boostrap link:
[image]

Here the style of the header:

```
.headerStyle {
  background-color: black;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  display: flex;
}
```

Here the header in React JS:

```
 <div className="headerStyle" style={{ height: 60 }}>

    <div style={{ flexDirection: 'row', display: 'flex' }}>
      <ButtonSection name="Home" path="/" />
      <ButtonSection name="About" path="/about" />
      <ButtonSection name="Contact Us" path="/contactUs" />
    </div>

    <div style={{ justifyContent: 'space-evenly', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <SignUpButton />
      <LoginButton />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Maybe apply some padding?

Comment: @Andy the problem is that I wanna know why bootstrap conflict with my css. I won't add a padding because isn't a right answer for thi sproblem (and I think that it will give me some problems with the responsive design)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the `<p></p>` tag, there aren't any other solution, if you wanna write a text use only `<div></div>` and don't `<p></p>`

Answer (score 0):

Try and add align-items: 'center' to .headerStyle

```
.headerStyle {
   background-color: black;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: space-between;
   display: flex;
   align-items: 'center'
 }
```